# how to obtain value_index for configurable product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Ive been following the Magento 2 tutorials for creating a configurable product. Ive come across a problem whereby the documentation seems to skip over it.

"The value assigned to the value_index must be unique within the system."

```
{
    "option": {
        "attribute_id": "141",
        "label": "Size",
        "position": 0,
        "is_use_default": true,
        "values": [{
            "value_index": 9
        }]
    }
}
```

Whilst the rest of the tutorial provides an easy to follow the process, Im completely stumped on how to obtain the value_index value.

I've tried removing the key altogether and it throws an error, I've also tried entering random numbers and also the id of the newly created child items, but no luck.

Has anyone got any suggestions on how to obtain the next index value for this area when creating the required record?

Tutorial Link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/define-config-product-options.html

P.S. I've also googled this on the Magento forums and can't find a clear answer on this topic, so any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem couple days ago and after days of googling I've made simple counter starting with some bigger number (99999 in my solution) and I generate new unique number for each configuration of product. This is not a clean solution but it seems to work so...

If you find something better please let me know

```
function GetNextConfigurableAttId(){
    $sessionKey = "configurableattributeid";
    $id = 99999;
    if(isset($_SESSION[$sessionKey])){
        $id = $_SESSION[$sessionKey];
    }
    $id++;
    $_SESSION[$sessionKey] = $id++;
    return $id;
}
```